# Why does adding 'debuggable true' to my Android release build type eliminate a cryptic error?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I've been developing on an app for a while and testing against the debug build type with no build issues.  Today, I tried building the release build type and I get the error

Error: Expected resource of type drawable [ResourceType]

This error occurs in a Butterknife-generated .java file.  After quite a bit of trial and error (including doing a clean and invalidating caches) I discovered that the build succeeds if I add `debuggable true` to the release build type in my app build.gradle file, thus:

```
release {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
```

It also builds if I comment out the other properties thus:

```
release {
    debuggable true
    //minifyEnabled true
    //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
```

But the build fails as before if I also comment out `debuggable true`.  So it appears that no matter what I need to have `debuggable true` in my release build type even though I don't want it there.

Any ideas what might be causing this?  More importantly, any idea how I can get the error to go away without `debuggable true` and without suppressing lint warnings?

(I've tried suppressing the lint error ResourceType on the particular declaration in the hand-coded .java file but to no avail.  TBH, I don't want to go into production with a solution like that.)

Comment: We are also facing a similar issue. You could fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are facing an obfuscation problem.
Proguard is used to remove dead code and shrink your package size before installing. Typically minifyEnabled = true on release builds. making it debuggable likely prevents it from doing this.

There is a proguards rule file that tells it to make exceptions. Here is how it works.

Proguard combs your code and looks for unused code like "lint" and then removes it as no one ever calls the code.

However, tools like Bus or Butterknife use reflection or annotation to access code. This makes the IDE and LINT believe it is unused and it gets removed. therefore the code will not compile in release properly as it will be missing necessary components for the project to function.

Consider either setting minifyEnable = false
or
try adding this to your proguard rules file

```
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
```

If that still doesn't work, you may have something else going on. The strange part is the missing "resource" piece, it makes me think that unused resources are being removed due to butterknife as well. So I would not leave debuggable in there, I would just set minifyEnabled = false if the above solution doesn't fix it.

If that doesn't work, then try running:

bash gradlew assembleRelease --debug and look for the actual complaints and problems from there.

Best of luck and hopefully that fixes ya.

Comment: The proguard rules file already has those rules.  Plus, as I said in the original description, the build fails when I comment out everything in the build type configuration.  Commenting out everything means that proguard is not in effect and minifyEnabled is false (I also tried setting it to false explicitly, but still got the same error).  Therefore, it seems to me that it is not an issue with either of these.  Running gradle with --debug yielded nothing of interest.  Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: Hmm only other thing I would say to try then is change your build variant from lower left menu to release and try getting it to compile so that you don't have to find out when generating APKs, you can at least get errors while doing regular builds if your problem is in release builds. If you want to create a sample project to share, I'm happy to help troubleshoot, but anything else would just be guessing and checking. But personally I would stop using Butterknife. Android introduced Data Binding and it is so much better once you get used to it, it is amazing :).